# I am getting maven dependency problems in a fresh project generated from start.spring.io. How can I fix this?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot, maven

[image]

I have not touched anything in the pom file. The fresh project shows 99 maven dependency problems. I generated the project from start.spring.io by adding various dependencies like lombok, spring data jpa, java mail, spring web etc. Why am I getting this and how can I solve this? I am attaching the pom without the build tag because I was getting an error while posting this question.

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.8</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.integrity</groupId>
<artifactId>signup</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>signup</name>
<description>POC</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: What problems? Post the errors not a nebulous statement.

Comment: You wrote `The fresh project shows 99 maven dependency problems` what are those problems? Have you build on plain command line? What is the output?

Comment: It was not possible to write all the problems down. So I have edited my question and added the screenshot. Please check that out once again. Sorry for not doing this earlier.

Comment: Please do not use images better use text...apart from that try to build on plain command line and post the error output...apart from that I suppose you have some network/firewall/proxy issues...

Answer (score 1):

First thing to check if your system has maven installed or not?
If this is the freshly created spring project in eclipse, then you should do following steps to avoid most of the errors:

1. Right click on project, go to Maven and update project. Keep looking at the bottom right to see progress.
2. Click on Project from tool bar at top and clean all the project.
3. Right click on the project and go to java build path. Click on Libraries, verify if the project is using correct JRE version.
4. Right-click on your project and choose Properties to open the Project Properties dialog. There is a Project Facets item on the left, select it, look for the Java facet on the list, choose which version you want to use for the project and apply, always make sure that the version selected is available on your system.

I hope that these points would make most of the errors go away. Let me know if you still see any issue, otherwise you can just do a copy paste on google and you should get the answer to your errors.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. After googling things for a bit I switched to STS from eclipse and imported the same project. In STS there are no issues at all. I am new to all of this. I don't know how and why everything is working fine in STS.